# How do I set Gmail to use my default account?

Tags: gmail

My settings are set correctly, so this appears to be a bug.

## Details:

I've checked my settings and my `****@xona.com` account is set to be the default, but it is not chosen as such.

Upon each new email I compose, it's now offering me to choose between my Gmail address `********@gmail.com` or my default account `****@xona.com`, instead of just using my default account.

Worst still, the choice defaults to my Gmail address `********@gmail.com`! Besides, I don't want the choice, and I want the default to be my default account!

I also have `When replying to a message:` set to `Always reply from default address (currently ****@xona.com)`.

Comment: I am having the same problem as well, It just started this afternoon. I have my work address set as the default but Gmail is choosing the @gmail.com account as the default instead. Maybe there is a bug in the Gmail system?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, started about a day or so back. I checked my settings and my default account has been marked but when I click on compose, it give me options but with my gmail account as the first option. If I dont check any other account, it will send via gmail which isnt my default marked account. However when i reply to an email it uses my default account. I would appreciate if a solution to this is found. Tks!

Comment: Same problem here, this seems like a new bug in Gmail.

Comment: No. I do not remember this problem anymore. It must have been a glitch they later fixed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a bug that could not be reproduced later on.