# Did Gmail change their option for default composing From field?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Gmail to use my default account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27632/how-do-i-set-gmail-to-use-my-default-account)

I have several accounts attached to my gmail account. One of them is set up as a "default". I also have the flag "Always reply from default address."

Yet, when I compose a message, I get in the From field the gmail address!

This was never a problem before, I am not sure what changed. I tried deleting my email, and re-adding it as default, it did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's still working correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me also.
Just log out, and log back in, and it should sort itself out.

Comment: Who knew that actually helps sometimes...